# Java сортировка двумерного массива по элементу [i][1]

Tags: java, матрицы, double

Есть вопрос, есть двумерный String массив, к примеру ***{{"Слово1","5"},{"Слово2","0"},{"Слово3","3"},{"Слово4","1"}}***

Как отсортировать массив по второму элементу каждого? Нужно получить:
***{{"Слово2","0"},{"Слово4","1"},{"Слово3","3"},{"Слово1","5"}}***

Используя *Array.sort()* справится с этой задачей не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать компаратор для сравнения.

Если вы хотите отсортировать в лексикографическом порядке, то это можно сделать так:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(o -> o[1]));
```

Если вы хотите сравнивать элементы как числа, то так:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.valueOf(o[1])));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй вариант подошёл, все работает.